# How to create group and assign privileges to Group in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am implementing a Sales process where it includes 3 set of users. Set 1 consists of Sales Analyst, Set 2 consists of Sales managers, and Set 3 consists of Sales Directors.

In my sales Process, I am using 3 different Process flows against an opportunity. If users under Set 1 logs in they only need to see views and Process assigned to Set 1 users and same in the case for other Set users (Set 2, Set 3).

Is it possible to create a group/profile and assign users to it, so that in future if I create any view or process I only need to assign that process/Views to a particular Set (Set1, Set 2, Set 3)?

Is it possible to achieve through Dynamics?

Answer (score 1):

2 different things.

**Business process flow**: To show only BPF1 to Set1 (sales analysts), create a security role (or use existing sales analyst role which might have assigned to only Set1 users), map this role to BPF1 using “Enable Security Role” option

[image]

**Catch**: so far created records with BPF1 will still show it for Set2 users.

**Views**: To show PublicView1 only to Set1, there’s no easy way to regulate it using Team or Security roles. But you can create Personal view & share with Set1 users or a Set1Team (add all Set1 users to this team)

Comment: I created 3 new roles and assign each business process to the corresponding role. But when Set 1 users completes the process and Set 2 users opens the record , he wont be seeing any process flow. But if he open the Process and try to switch the process its working. Is it possible to show process flow based on role. Say if a user from set 1 open the opportunity his role will be checked and only BPF1 will be set to that particular user.

Comment: @Cyber mark/upvote this answer if it helped you in posted question. Ask a new question for different problem. 1 question in 1 post wrt SO Q&A..

Comment: @Cyber btw, BPF is for each entity record not for user. Whoever opens first will get the BPF set/see right in that record. It can’t switch for each user, may be abandon functionality you are looking for? Still BPF can be set in JS on form load based on user/role.